# Compare several dirs and indentify unique files

Tags: python, scripting

Is this a good way to identify unique filenames in a set of dirs?

I tried this in python, reading the dir structure into a dict and then working on a deep copy of the dict:

```
for subdirs, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        if dir not in dir_dict:
            dir_dict[dir] = []
        else:
           dir_dict[dir].append(file)

copy_dict = copy.deepcopy(dir_dict)
def delete_but_uniques(dir_dict):
    for dir_key in dir_dict:
        dir_list = dir_dict[dir_key]
        current_dir = copy_dict.pop(dir_key)
        for file_list in dir_list:
            for other_dir in current_dir:
                if file in current_dir:
                    if file in dir_list:
                        dir_list.remove(file)
    copy_dict[dir_key] = current_dir
```

But the dictionary doesnt look like the dir, either it loads all files into the same key or creates the correct keys but without the values.

I'd like to know
a) what I am doing wrong and
b) if that's a good approach at all.

---

### Edit:

My directory looks like this:

```
    dir/    
   folder_1/a.txt b.txt c.txt    
   folder_2/b.txt c.txt d.txt e.txt f.txt    
   folder_3/b.txt c.txt e.txt g.txt    
   ...    
   folder_n/
```

I want to remove all non-uniques across all dirs, so that I have:

```
    dir/    
   folder_1/a.txt    
   folder_2/d.txt f.txt    
   folder_3/g.txt    
   ...
   folder_n/
```

I am open to any language or approach suggested to solve this problem.

---

### Edit 2:

I solved it with fdupes:
fdupes -r * > deletethesefiles
and then ran a bash script on that file.

Comment: It would be great if you add an example of what your directory looks like and what kind of output you expect.

Comment: @Thomas How should I use rsync? Compare dir by dir?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.